# Matplotlib stackplot area color is being negated

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm running into an issue when I create a stackplot where (I think) the colors for the areas are being negated. I can't really explain what is going on so I uploaded a photo of it. I've tried reversing the order of the list, creating sublists of the x values, removing the seaborn colors and the alpha value, but I can't seem to find a fix. Please let me know if you have insight into this!

Here is the code:

```
def graph_stack_plot(account_list):
    dataframe_list = []
    label_list = []
    for i, account in enumerate(account_list):
        label_list.append("account-{}".format(i))
        data = {
            "date": [x.datetime for x in account.full_transaction_list],
            label_list[-1]: [x.account_balance for x in account.full_transaction_list]
        }
        dataframe_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list(data.keys())))

    full_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframe_list)
    full_dataframe = full_dataframe.where(pd.notnull(full_dataframe), 0)

    plt.stackplot(
        full_dataframe["date"].tolist(),
        [full_dataframe[label].tolist() for label in label_list],
        labels=label_list,
        colors=sns.color_palette("Set1"),
        alpha=0.4
    )
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Update 1:

When I comment out the  full_dataframe = full_dataframe.where(pd.notnull(full_dataframe), 0) line which converts the NaNs to zeros, the plot only shows the red area and not the blue, green, and purple areas even though they are still on the legend.

[image]

Update 2:

I thought that maybe the stacked plot needed a value for every single x value, so I modified the code to replace all NaNs with either preceding values or zeros. Here is the modified code and what the graph looks like now:
[image]
As a note, I changed the index of the dataframe to be the date column I had, so that is why the x values are using full_dataframe.index and not full_dataframe["date"].

Comment: Maybe a stackplot isn't appropriate when the columns also contain negative values?

Comment: No negative values, lowest values are 0 or NaN.

Comment: Did you try replacing the NaNs with zeros?

Comment: My bad, I actually did replace the NaNs with zeros with the full_dataframe = full_dataframe.where(pd.notnull(full_dataframe), 0) line. When I comment that out, it actually only shows the red area even though the blue, green, and purple are still on the legend and being appended to the stacked plot.

Comment: I just added a screenshot for what is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe's index was not sorted....

My assumption was that the index column of the dataframe would be ordered regardless of the type. I feel like that shouldn't have caused the problems I was facing, but I guess I have much to learn about matplotlib.